# Kubernetes shared File System across Pods

Tags: kubernetes

A question that I can’t seem to find a good answer to and am so confused as to what should be an easy answer. I guess you can say I can't see the forest for the trees.

I have N Pods that need access to the same shared FILE SYSTEM (contains 20Gig of pdfs, HTML) only read. I don’t want to copy it to each Pod and create a Volume in Docker. How should I handle this? I don’t see this as a Stateful App where each pod gets its own changed data.

- Node-0

  - Pod-0

    - Java-app  - NEED READ ACCESS TO SHARED FILE SYSTEM
- Node-1

  - Pod-1

    - Java-app  - NEED READ ACCESS TO SHARED FILE SYSTEM
- Node-2

  - Pod-2

    - Java-app  - NEED READ ACCESS TO SHARED FILE SYSTEM

Comment: What approaches have you tried (or considered) already?  Have you read through the documentation on [Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) and especially the list of volume types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is quite open-ended. However having gone through this thought process recently, I can come up with two options:

1. [**hostPath**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath): You mount this data (probably from NFS or some such) at `/data` (for example) on all your Kubernetes nodes. Then in Pod specification, you attach volume of type `hostPath` with `path: /data`.
2. [**GlusterFS volume**](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#glusterfs): This is the option we finally went for, for high availability and speed requirements. The same GlusterFS volume (having the PDFs, data, etc.) can be attached to multiple Pods.

Answer (score 1):

The persistent volume [access mode](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) is called `ReadOnlyMany`.  Not all volume plugins or CSI drivers support this mode (the [linked docco](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) maintains a table for support).

If you are hosting on EKS/AKS/GKE they all provide services based on file shares that can do it. Elsewhere you can use an NFS server.